# Is it possible to use dynamic host_vars files?

Tags: ansible

I'm aware I can add host variables dynamically via an inventory script. I'm wondering if I can scripts in the host_vars directory which will be executed instead of simple read.

I have tried to create a simple script that outputs some variables. It seems only .json and .yml or no extension are read by the ansible-playbook. Since these are not executed the raw source will result in an error.

So, hence the question. Is this even possible and if not, would you be aware of a method to achieve the same results: Query a (local) dynamic source for variables of a particular host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure [`lookup("pipe")`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/lookup/pipe.html) will do what you want, provided the script is available on the target host:

```
- set_fact:
    my_vars: '{{ lookup("pipe", "./my_script.py") | from_json }}'
```

(substituting `from_json` with `from_yaml` or whatever to coerce the textual output from the script into a python datastructure; it's *possible* that ansible would coerce it automagically, but explicit is better than implicit)

If you want the script that is on the *control* machine to run, you'll likely have to do some hoopjumpery with `delegate_to:` and some `hostvars` ninjary to promote the `set_fact:` off of the control host over to all playbook hosts